# Group By Having Count in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Here is my data:

```
{'SystemID': {0: '95EE8B57',
 1: '5F891F03',
 2: '5F891F03',
 3: '5F891F03'},
 'Day': {0: '06/08/2018', 1: '05/08/2018', 2: '04/08/2018',   3: '05/08/2018'},
 'AlarmClass-S': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 0},
 'AlarmClass-ELM': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 2}}
```

I would like to perform an aggregation and filtering which in SQL would be formulated as

```
SELECT SystemID, COUNT(*) as count FROM table GROUP BY SystemID HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Thus the result shall be

```
    {'SystemID': {0: '5F891F03'},
 'count': {0: '3'}}
```

How to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `count`, then filter at the end.

```
(df.groupby('SystemID', as_index=False)['SystemID']
   .agg({'count': 'count'})
   .query('count > 2'))

   SystemID  count
0  5F891F03      3
```

---

```
(df.groupby('SystemID', as_index=False)['SystemID']
   .agg({'count': 'count'})
   .query('count > 2')
   .to_dict())
# {'SystemID': {0: '5F891F03'}, 'count': {0: 3}}
```